# $k[x]$-module structure on finite dimensional $k$- vector space $V$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $k$ be a finite field. Describe upto isomorphism all $k[x]$-module structure on finite dimensional  $k$- vector space $V$.

By the structure theorem for modules over PIDs I know that if $V$ is a $k[x]$-module, then $V$ can be written as direct sum of a quotient of $k[x]$. What else can we say about this?

Comment: Hint: You only have to understand how $x$ acts on $V$. Since $V$ is finite-dimensional you can represent the operator $x$ by a matrix. This matrix can be put into Jordan canonical form. How many such forms are there?

Comment: @Mathematician42: Sorry,how does one counts this?

Comment: Using the Jordan canonical form theorem you can count the number of non-isomorphic Jordan matrices of the proper size. Show that two modules are isomorphic if and only if the Jordan matrices are isomorphic.

Comment: Do you mean, describe *up to isomorphism*? Otherwise, the module structures are in bijection with linear operators.

Comment: @lhf: Yeah i'm interested in upto isomorphism only.